# why is this true? $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let's say I get to this 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

How do I justify that first reduction?  Do you intuit that, or is there some algebraic cancel/reduction involved?

Again, why is this true? 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

Comment: Is it always true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x).\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$ assuming both limits are finite?

Comment: Yes, the limit operation distributes over products, assuming the inner limits are finite.

Comment: @CarlLove : then it should be done... $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}.\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ assuming that one know $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$

Comment: Thanks.  This forum rocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=l$ Then $\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)]^2=l^2$

more generally If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=l$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=m$ Then

$\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)\times g(x)]=[\lim_{x\to a} f(x)]\times [\lim_{x\to a} g(x)]$

Comment: (Whenever the limits on the right hand exist.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It's only true by sheer luck. We know by the product rule of limits $$lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {\text{sin}^2(x)} {x^2} = \left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac {\text{sin}(x)} x \right)^2 = 1^2 = 1$$

If the inside limit had been anything other than $0$ or $1$ - i.e., the solutions to $x^2=x$ - that would have been wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since function $$f(y) = y^2 \ , \quad y \in \mathbb{R}$$ is **continuous** and you know that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0\ ,$ it follows that $f(\frac{\sin}{x}) \to f(1)$ as $x \to 0\ .$ In other words, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2} = 1^2 \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

The magic words are "L'Hopital" and "double angle formula". The first tells you that

$$\lim \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} = \lim \frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{2 x}.$$

The second tells you that $2\sin x \cos x = \sin 2 x.$

Comment: (No need for that, though.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff "Need" is an interesting term.

Comment: ..Very cool technique...........

Answer (score 0):

Just use some algebra. Because 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
we have 
$$
1\cdot 1 \cdot \cdots 1=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdots\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^n x}{x^n}=1
$$
where the product is taken $n$ times.

Comment: That should be limit at 0, not infinity.

Comment: My apologies, I will fix this.